# Возвращаемый класс функции dll

Tags: java, dll, jna

Я обращаюсь к dll-функциям из java с помощью jna. 
Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, что должна возвращать функция. Как мне узнать возвращаемый класс? 
Сейчас кидает ошибку "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported return type class", но не говорит, какой класс должен быть.

```
public static class SomeDLL {

    public interface SomeDLLLibrary extends Library {

        SomeDLLLibrary someDLL = (SomeDLLLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("SomeDLL", SomeDLLLibrary.class);

        boolean init(Integer pointer);

        byte[] getDeviceInfo(String addr, Integer port, Integer protocolType);

    }

}
```

Comment: а что написано после Unsupported return type class?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported return type class [B in function getDeviceInfo
 at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:379)
 at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:231)
 at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:216)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.AclasSDK_GetDeviceInfo(Unknown Source)

Comment: можно попробовать сначала указать возвращаемый тип Object, затем в исполняемом коде дёрнуть так `Class a = someDll.getDeviceInfo().getClass();   
        System.out.println("Class of getDeviceInfoobj is : " + a.getName());`

Comment: @Komdosh к сожалению, не прокатило, ошибка всё равно:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported return type class java.lang.Object in function getDeviceInfo